# UWP MVVM design pattern, failed to set DataContext

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, mvvm-light, uwp-xaml

so I can't find the problem in the code, I must have missed something.
this is the locator viewmodel:

```
using Airport.FlightService;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc;
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;

namespace Airport.ViewModel
{
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<FlightViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IReportService, ReportServiceClient>();
    }

    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public FlightViewModel FlightVM
    {
        get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<FlightViewModel>(); }
    }

    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        // TODO Clear the ViewModels
    }
 }
}
```

and here is my view xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="Airport.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Airport"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=FlightVM}">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
</Grid>
</Page>
```

and of the app.xaml:

```
<Application
x:Class="Airport.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Airport"
xmlns:vm="using:Airport.ViewModel"
RequestedTheme="Light">
<!--xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
d1p1:Ignorable="d" 
xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"-->

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Dictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"></vm:ViewModelLocator>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

`FlightVM` is a viewmodel that inherets from `ViewModelBase` I have in my `ViewModel` folder
it doesnt let me set the `datacontext` in the view, it marks the `DataContext=...` and says `"failed to set datacontext"` what am I missing? it doesnt mark any othe problem and I really have no idea, the message isn't informative at all

Comment: Does the code actually compile? The ViewModelLocator file seems to have wrong curly brace pairs. The `Register` calls should probably be inside the constructor, but it does not seem so from the code

Comment: you are right, I missed a few lines of code when I copied it, I edited the topic so now it is shown correctly

Comment: How do you know that DataContext is not getting set ?

Comment: it marks it with blue underline and says "cannot set datacontext" it aint a compile error, it rebuilds just fine but the code doesnt work because of that

Answer (score 0):

The ViewModelLocator code misses some lines from the constructor. Can you provide the full source?

The constructor should start by initializing the ServiceLocator with a locator provider. Something like this:

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
```

Comment: you are right, I missed a few lines of code when I copied it, I edited the topic so now it is shown correctly

Comment: Also, put the locator above merged dictionaries

Comment: I can't find any problems with the code you supplied. It does work; even when you put the locator above the merged dictionaries. I assume you inject the report service into your view models? Can you try first without injecting dependencies and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your error by deliberately causing an error in the dependency injection part. 
Assuming that your FlightViewModel injects the IReportService, I get the exact same error when:

- Adding a constructor to ReportServiceClient with arguments (without supplying a default constructor)

OR

- Adding a default constructor to ReportServiceClient that throws an exception.

The ServiceLocator will fail to create the FlightViewModel instance.

You should get a runtime exception as well.

For a solution: If there is no default constructor in your injected services, supply one or register it with the right arguments. If you do have default constructors, set a breakpoint at the top of the constructors of your injected classes and debug any exceptions you get.